# Docker not responding on PHPUnit test

Tags: php, api, unit-testing, docker, phpunit

I am using Docker in my PHP project and everything has been working fine until now.

My API has an endpoint that needs to call another endpoint within the same API. So, doing a post to /hello will make, eventually a call to /x.

In order to make that call I do the following:

```
$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => $url,
    'headers' => [
    'Accept' => 'application/hal+json',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ],
]);

$response = $client->post('/x', [
    'form_params' => [
    'username' => $email,
    'password' => $password,
    ],
]);
```

Where the URL is the exactly the same as the first one, but for the new endpoint. For example, if the POST is for: www.mydomain.com:8880/hello, the new call will be made to www.mydomain.com:8880/x.

Now, this is working fine with the exception of the tests. PHPUnit (which runs inside a docker container) starts its web server on localhost:8880, and when making that second call (so it will try to call localhost:8880/x) it will be hanging forever.

I've tried changing that second call to 127.0.0.1:8880/x, but that didn't work either.

Any ideas on what the problem is and how can it be fixed?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show how you are running your containers and how you are also running phpunit?

Comment: which webserver are you using? is xdebug enabled?